# Print pretty data.frames/tables to console

Tags: r, printing, console, dataframe

Is there a way to print small `data.frames` to the console in a more readable manner?

For example, would it be possible to output to the console:

```
library(MASS)   
iris[1:5, ]

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

as

```
iris[1:5, ]

  +--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
  | Sepal.Length | Sepal.Width | Petal.Length | Petal.Width | Species |
  +--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
1 |          5.1 |         3.5 |          1.4 |         0.2 |  setosa |
2 |          4.9 |         3.0 |          1.4 |         0.2 |  setosa |
3 |          4.7 |         3.2 |          1.3 |         0.2 |  setosa |
4 |          4.6 |         3.1 |          1.5 |         0.2 |  setosa |
5 |          5.0 |         3.6 |          1.4 |         0.2 |  setosa |
  +--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
```

I realise for large `data.frames` it would take up an unnecessary amount of time, but if it's an option, I would like to be able to look at small frames in a more structured manner.

In particular, when I have two text fields next to each other, it would be much easier with a pipe between the two fields to separate them, as the spacing between words is the same size as the spacing between columns.

Thanks

Comment: How about `View(iris[1:5,])`?

Comment: Have you tried `dplyr` package? It has `tbl_df` function to convert to what Hadley Wickham calls a local data.frame. It is supposed to (and does, IMO) provide more structured and readable output when printing to console. It does not provide separators between fields though.

Comment: Yeah, I've used both of them. And I'd like it to print the console because I need to interactively change some values between two tables which involves some interpretation of text for ~250 values, so I'm just trying to make it a bit easier to manage. I'm also using `data.table` for the most part - the output of which i find preferable to `dplyr`'s.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In case it helps anyone, I just stumbled across the fact that `knitr`'s `kable` achieves a nice pretty print. Combine with some of the `.Rprofile` suggestions above, this seems to achieve what I had in mind.

```
> knitr::kable(head(iris))

| Sepal.Length| Sepal.Width| Petal.Length| Petal.Width|Species |
|------------:|-----------:|------------:|-----------:|:-------|
|          5.1|         3.5|          1.4|         0.2|setosa  |
|          4.9|         3.0|          1.4|         0.2|setosa  |
|          4.7|         3.2|          1.3|         0.2|setosa  |
|          4.6|         3.1|          1.5|         0.2|setosa  |
|          5.0|         3.6|          1.4|         0.2|setosa  |
|          5.4|         3.9|          1.7|         0.4|setosa  |
```

Comment: As of knitr 1.16, this is no longer the case (i.e. it no longer pretty prints). @yihui - any ideas?

Comment: @Shantanu Works for me with knitr_1.17

Comment: @G5W Thanks for reporting. I realized that the issue is something related to Rmd chunks. In RStudio, create a new Rmd file, execute a chunk (any chunk), then run `knitr::kable(head(iris))`. The output now doesn't look as clean (e.g. it include `attr(,"format")` `attr(,"class")` `attr(,"knit_cacheable")` etc.)

Comment: you can now change the print format with the `format` argument. E.g., the above table would be printed with `knitr::kable(head(iris), format = "markdown")`

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem recently and came across the `huxtable` package. It is very flexible and maybe a litte overkill for just nicer console output, but it served me very well.

Here is how you could solve your problem using `huxtable`:

```
library(huxtable)
library(magrittr)

small_iris <- iris[1:5, ]

iris_hux <- 
  hux(small_iris) %>% 
  add_colnames() %>% 
  set_bold(row = 1, col = everywhere, value = TRUE) %>% 
  set_all_borders(TRUE)
```

I think all functions speak for themselves. For a thorough introduction, see https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/huxtable.html#adding-row-and-column-names.

`print_screen(iris_hux)` yield this output (in the console!):

[image]

*I have not figured out yet how to suppress the bottom information on the column names. So if someone knows, please comment!*

**EDIT:** In order to suppress the column names at the bottom, use `colnames = FALSE` inside `print_screen()`.

Comment: Note that in general you shouldn't need to use `print_screen`: just evaluating `iris_hux` would do the same thing.

Comment: is there a way to suppress scientific notation? This: options(scipen = 999) does not work

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of methods you could try.

1. Add a couple of helper functions to your `.Rprofile`. In my profile, I have

   ```
   hh = function(d) 
      if(class(d)=="matrix"|class(d)=="data.frame") d[1:5,1:5]
   ```

   This function prints the top left hand corner of the data frame. I also have

   ```
   ht = function(d, n=6) rbind(head(d, n), tail(d,n))
   ```
2. Create your own `S3` print function for data frames, e.g.

   ```
   print.data.frame = function(x, ..., digits = NULL, 
                           quote = FALSE, right = TRUE, 
                           row.names = TRUE) 
                       message("hi")
   ```
3. Use a package, e.g. `dplyr`. However, this is a bit overkill if all you want is pretty printing.

Comment: All I do want is pretty printing. The objects are `data.tables` anyway, so are default printed as `5 head`, `5 tail` rows. Thanks for the `pretty` keyword though. Seems like a more appropriate title.

Comment: If you want to pretty print, then create function called `print.data.table`. When a data table is printed to the screen, that function will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are also open to printing your output into the (RStudio) viewer pane rather than the console, I would recommend using the `DT` package.

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
```

This has several advantages, I think: the output is pretty and well-arranged, the package is able to display large data frames without becoming cumbersome and it is highly customizable to boot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*tibble*s are printed with colour formatting in the console:

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- as_tibble(mtcars)
x
```

[image]