# How to create image of a table from data frame in R-Programming

Tags: r, powerbi

How to convert data in a data frame into a graphic of a table?

I have my data in the `dataframe` and want to convert it into the graphic so that I can display it using the software Power BI.

e.g.:

```
x <- data.frame(Sex=c("M", "M", "F", "F", "F"), Color=c("brown", "blue", "brown", "brown", "brown"))
```

This is my data frame. Want to display the table with columns as sex and color and respective data in it.

Typing `X` in R gives output as  image 1. I want to display the output as 2

[image: Default print output]

[image: Expected output]

Comment: how is the picture different from what "x" already has? Do you it in a .csv file or something?

Comment: I want this is tabular graph. x is giving me data but I cant plot it. In Power BI we can display plotted graph only and not data. Another thing is x gives data without the lines in the sense without formatting. I need it in proper table format.

Comment: Some answers on this post may also help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374688/print-pretty-data-frames-tables-to-console

Answer (score 1):

You can create tables in the graphics window with something like:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
grid.table(x)
```

Otherwise have a look at `knitr` and `pander` or `xtable` for producing tables in Word/HTML documents.

Comment: Thanks this works. Do you have any idea how to install functions in powerbi. This query is working in R studio but as power bi doesn't have package installed in getting error as function doesn't found.

Comment: @mohang, Sorry I've no experience with Power BI. If you want to bring the question to the attention of people with that knowledge, you'll need to add the tag `powerbi`.

Comment: Hey, just a query,How to achieve above expected result without using the package gridextra?

Comment: @mohang now `gridExtra` is supported in `powerBI`. Refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-r-packages-support