# Visualize a table

Tags: r

I want to move the data that I already have into a table with two columns. One shows a list of the intervals and the other their frequency.

I just want to visualize that in something like R graphics (like what I did with `hist()`).

```
intervalsCO2

[0,1.85]  (1.85,3.7]  (3.7,5.55]  (5.55,7.4]  (7.4,9.25] (9.25,11.1]   (11.1,13] (13,14.8] 

2         6           11          20          33          63           29         38
```

This would be my "table: `intervalsCO2`" in Console. But I want it as an image (not a graph). Like the table below:

[image]

Comment: I do not understand what you want. You currently have a table. You say that you want an image that is not a graph. Can you give an example of what you want? Perhaps a histogram?

Comment: @DDT read about ***[`DT` package](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/)***

Comment: Duplicate of [Print pretty data.frames/tables to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374688/print-pretty-data-frames-tables-to-console)

Comment: @Gregor Save the html table as an image!!! you are pulling my leg, right?

Comment: No... do you know a nice easy R command to save an HTML table as an image file? I'm not aware of one.

Comment: From OP's image, I think `gridExtra::tableGrob` is more like what OP is looking for, e.g., [like this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html). But it seems OP is maybe already using that? Is the question about how to save tables as images or how to transform the `intervalsCO2` data (looks like `table(cut())` output) into something usable by `tableGrob`. OP, please post your code so far, and also share your input with `dput` so it's copy/pasteable? `dput(intervalsCO2)` would be great.

Comment: @Gregor well, if you have the right IDE it will do it for you. otherwise `library(gridExtra);library(grid);grid.table(df)`

Comment: I don't see any of that at your proposed dupe... doesn't look like any of the answers use `grid` or `gridExtra`.

Comment: Here we go @Gregor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418585/how-to-create-image-of-a-table-from-data-frame-in-r-programming