# View for two-way tables in R

Tags: r

I would like to nicely print two-way tables in R. The R base command `table()`, allows you to print the two-way table but I would like something like `View()` so that the outcome can better be visualised. However, when I apply `View()` to `table()` the outcome is no more a two-way table. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(1)

smoking_habits <- data.frame(gender = c(rep("M",10), rep("F",10)),
                             smoke = rbinom(20,1,0.3))

table(smoking_habits)

View(table(smoking_habits))
```

Is there a function that allows me to easily do so?

Comment: Can this help?  [Print pretty data.frames/tables to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374688/print-pretty-data-frames-tables-to-console)

Comment: @Ale, I don't think so because the linked question deals with `data.frame` printing while the question here is printing / viewing a `table` object

Comment: I think this is a dupe, please try this: `knitr::kable(table(smoking_habits))`

Answer (score 2):

The result of `table` turns into long format when converted to a data frame; this is useful for indexing. If you do not want this to happen, use `unclass`:

```
View(unclass(table(smoking_habits)))
```