# underline column names in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, crayon

How do you underline column names in R?

I tried saving a string and then using that with

```
library(crayon)

string1 <- underline("hello")
string2 <- underline("hello2")

colnames(table) <- c(string1, string2)
```

However string1 prints as `"\033[4mhello\033[24m"`.

String2 prints as `"\033[4mhello2\033[24m"`

Please let me know how I can get the column names to be underlined.

I just want the column names to stand out, even changing the colour of the text when it prints to the console would be fine

Comment: What packages are you using for "underline" function?

Comment: crayon package. I just want to underline the column names in a dataframe, supprised its not easy to find

Comment: Maybe look into DT, knitr packages?

Comment: Theres nothing useful there. Even changing the colour of the text would be good. Cant seem to find anything anywhere.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32374688/680068

Answer (score 2):

The default printing code for matrices and data.frames internally handles non-printable characters, and escapes them. That’s why the ANSI escape character code`'\033'` is escaped to `'\033', instead of being printed directly.

If you don’t want this, you will have to write your own `print.data.frame` function, [similar to how tibble does this](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/blob/10a25b9a1447901b469364f39081bfa15a7f270e/R/utils-format.R). Doing this properly requires a fair bit of logic (and thus, code). You could cheat, though:

```
print.data.frame = function (x, ...) {
    output = capture.output(base::print.data.frame(x, ...))
    colnames = crayon::underline(colnames(x))
    regmatches(output[1L], gregexpr('\\S+', output[1L]))[[1L]] = colnames
    cat(output, sep = '\n')
}
```

This *captures* the standard `print.data.frame` output, and replaces the first row (= the column headers) with an underscore-formatted version.

(Note that if there is whitespace in your column names, the above code **will fail**.)

Comment: I’ve given up making this code robust: fixing it for arbitrary column names in the general case would make the code vastly more complicated: once would have to search for the actual column names inside `output[1L]`. But a simple `regexpr` search (or equivalent) is insufficient, since column names might contain each other (e.g. `colnames = c('foobar', 'foo')`). To find the correct positions, one would need to progressively truncate the prefix, or build a more complex regular expression to capture all column headers at once.