# How to message an R data frame to the console?

Tags: r, dataframe

If I put a data frame to the console directly, it looks nice:

```
> head(datasets::mtcars, 4)
                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

How do I get the same nice output, but through `message` ?

```
> message(head(datasets::mtcars, 4))
c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4)c(6, 6, 4, 6)c(160, 160, 108, 258)c(110, 110, 93, 110)c(3.9, 3.9, 3.85, 3.08)c(2.62, 2.875, 2.32, 3.215)c(16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44)c(0, 0, 1, 1)c(1, 1, 1, 0)c(4, 4, 4, 3)c(4, 4, 1, 1)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374688/print-pretty-data-frames-tables-to-console) looks similar, but didn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `paste` to create a vector of values and pass it on to `message`

```
message(do.call(paste, c(head(datasets::mtcars, 4), collapse="\n")))
```

-output

```
# 21 6 160 110 3.9 2.62 16.46 0 1 4 4
#21 6 160 110 3.9 2.875 17.02 0 1 4 4
#22.8 4 108 93 3.85 2.32 18.61 1 1 4 1
#21.4 6 258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44 1 0 3 1
```

---

Inorder to get the row names attributes, we could use `capture.output`

```
message(paste(capture.output(head(datasets::mtcars, 4)), collapse="\n"))
```

-output

```
#                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```