# How to pretty print data tables using the same pretty printing of tibbles?

Tags: r, data.table, tibble

### Original question

I am developing an R data package that provides a bunch of data table objects.

When the user of my package asks for one of these data tables to be printed to the console, I would like them to be pretty printed just like tibbles are, i.e. nicely condensed, with column type at the top and some basic coloring of numbers, etc..

So would you know how to write a simple S3 method for data tables in my package? Perhaps this already exists implemented elsewhere but I could not find it.

I know there is this other question that is similar to this one: [Print pretty data.frames/tables to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374688/print-pretty-data-frames-tables-to-console), and that this has been partly answered by @csgillespie but he only leaves the suggestion that one could write an S3 method for data.frames. But given that I want to borrow the functionality already developed for tibbles (`tbl_df`), isn't there a simple mechanism of importing this either from the `{tibble}` package, or the `{pillar}` package where seemingly this functionality is nowadays originally implemented?

BTW: I do not want to simply convert the data table object to a tibble with e.g. `tibble::as_tibble()` because then I lose the advantages of having data table objects.

### Specific pretty printing of exported data tables

After @Waldi's answer, I thought of an alternative way that would only pretty print the data tables provided my package and not all of the data tables once my package is loaded. Here's my approach for which I would like your feedback.

1. Add the made-up class `dt_tbl` to the data table, in other words, subclass it:

```r
# Assume `dt` is one of the data tables provided by my package
class(dt) <- c('dt_tbl', class(dt))
```

2. Then in the R directory of my package, create a source file with the new S3 method for the class `"dt_tbl"`:

```r
# In file print_dt_tbl.R

#' @keywords internal
print_dt_tbl <- function(x, ...) {
  print_txt <- capture.output(print(tibble::as_tibble(x), ...))
  print_txt[1] <- sub('tibble', 'data.table', print_txt[1])
  cat(print_txt, sep = '\n')
  invisible(x)
}

#' @export
print.dt_tbl <- function(x, ...) {
  print_dt_tbl(x, ...)
}
```

3. Test it:

```r
> (iris_dt <- data.table::as.data.table(iris))
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
 ---                                                            
146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
> class(iris_dt) <- c('dt_tbl', class(iris_dt))
> iris_dt
# A data.table: 150 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# … with 140 more rows
```

Answer (score 3):

You coud modify `print.data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)

print_as_tibble <- function(dt) print(tibble::as_tibble(dt))

assignInNamespace("print.data.table", print_as_tibble , ns="data.table")

dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)

dt
#> # A tibble: 32 x 11
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> # ... with 22 more rows
class(dt)
#> [1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

To use this in your package, you could create a `.R` file with following `.onLoad`:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  print_as_tibble <- function(dt) print(tibble::as_tibble(dt))
  assignInNamespace("print.data.table", print_as_tibble , ns="data.table")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. So you create temporarily a tibble just for the printing? That is not too much of an expensive operation I guess...? And, where would I write that `assignInNamespace` command inside my R package? I'm asking this because I am not so versed with the namespaces. I usually follow the recommendations of https://r-pkgs.org/ and use roxygen tags to create my `NAMESPACE` file.

Comment: Yes, I just create a temporary tibble, and AFAIK it is a lazy operation which shouldn't be expensive. See edit for integration in package. Interested to know how it worked because I didn't use this up to now in my own packages.

Comment: Do you see any inconvenience with changing `print_as_tibble` with: `print_as_tibble <- function(dt) {
  print_txt <- capture.output(print(tibble::as_tibble(dt)))
  print_txt[1] <- sub('tibble', 'data.table', print_txt[1])
  cat(print_txt, sep = '\n')
} ` ?

Comment: `print_as_tibble <- function(dt) {
  print_txt <- capture.output(print(tibble::as_tibble(dt)))
  print_txt[1] <- sub('tibble', 'data.table', print_txt[1])
  cat(print_txt, sep = '\n')
  invisible(dt)
} `

Comment: Looks OK to me, good idea! The workaround I proposed is a quick hack, but you can extend / modify it as you wish

Comment: thanks! I am having second thoughts about this approach because overwriting `data.table`'s namespace has this side effect of all data tables (not just the exported ones by my package) now being printed with this method. Would you know how I could subclass my exported data tables and then provide a method for them based on `print_as_tibble`?

Comment: could you please provide feedback to my proposal to avoid pretty printing every data table after my package is loaded, and only do it for those data tables that carry the class `dt_tbl`?

Comment: Agree with the drawback of this solution. You could probably create your own class for your package and define `print.yourclass` from above code. I didn't test this though.

Answer (score 2):

There might be an easier way to implement some of the desired features.

According to `help("print.data.table", "data.table")` there are some printing options available for data.table objects, in particular the `class` and the `trunc.cols` options. The options can be set in `options()`. E.g.,

```
iris_dt <- data.table::as.data.table(iris)

options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)
options(datatable.print.trunc.cols = TRUE)

old_width <- options(width = 40)
iris_dt
options(old_width)
```

> ```
>      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
>             <num>       <num>
>   1:          5.1         3.5
>   2:          4.9         3.0
>   3:          4.7         3.2
>   4:          4.6         3.1
>   5:          5.0         3.6
>  ---                         
> 146:          6.7         3.0
> 147:          6.3         2.5
> 148:          6.5         3.0
> 149:          6.2         3.4
> 150:          5.9         3.0
> 3 variables not shown: [Petal.Length <num>, Petal.Width <num>, Species <fctr>]
> ```

For comparison

```
old_width <- options(width = 40)
tibble::as_tibble(iris_dt)
options(old_width)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 150 × 5
>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4
>  2          4.9         3            1.4
>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3
>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5
>  5          5           3.6          1.4
>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7
>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4
>  8          5           3.4          1.5
>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4
> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5
> # … with 140 more rows, and 2 more
> #   variables: Petal.Width <dbl>,
> #   Species <fct>
> ```

BTW, I prefer the data.table way of printing the first and the last rows of a large dataset.