# Color header (names) of a data.table in r in the console

Tags: r, colors, header, data.table

I am looking to color the header names of a data.table print in Rstudio.
Is this possible I do not find it.
I know that you can change a bit in the [options](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/print.data.table.html#examples) or use [kable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374688/print-pretty-data-frames-tables-to-console).

What about an option using the [package crayon](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/crayon/index.html)

Any suggestion where to begin ?

[image: screen from rstudio with kable and crayon]

The goal is to have this here :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We could use `colorDF` package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colorDF/vignettes/colorDF.html:

Here is are two examples: First is for red header using iris dataset:

**update** added `library(crayon)`

```
library(dplyr)
#install.packages("colorDF")
library(colorDF)
#updated
library(crayon)

iris1 <- iris %>% 
  head() %>% 
  as.colorDF()
df_style(iris1) <- list(col.names=list(fg="red")) 
iris1
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. In this case how could we modify print.default for data.frame/data.table to use colorDF ?

Comment: The answer does not yet help. From my glance at `colorDF` @DorianGrv would have to define a new theme, maybe based on 'minimal', that sets the column header.

Comment: Sorry we have to load the crayon package `library(crayon)` then we get the output with the red headers (my first output). I think this is the desired output?

Comment: The goal would be just to have the colnames of any data.frame/data.table with a color defined during a print in the console